# TestNG dependencies added but not getting run as TestNG option

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

I have added testNG dependencies in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupID>org.tesntNG</groupID>
<artfactID>testNG</artifactID>
<version>6.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am not getting an option of run as "TestNG"

Kindly help

Comment: What do you mean by `I am not getting an options of run as "TestNG"`? My assumption is that you are talking about Eclipse ? If Yes than you need to install Test NG plugin in Eclipse...this is not related to Maven...

Comment: You need to import testNG library into your project. Then while writing your test class in @Test annotation it will ask to import the testNg library into your project. It will show the Run as testNG option.